# Content Security Policy Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, protractor

Question - so I am trying to use the protractor-beautiful-reporter on my jenkins install.  This is an agular app.  However when the page is rendered showing that the angular bit isn't working.  Looking at the console for the page shows the following:

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a
>   resource at
>   https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js
>   (“script-src http://dskvm4981-iis:8080 'unsafe-inline'
>   'unsafe-eval'”).

I already use a couple of `setProperty` to override CSP for the machine.  These are:

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';")

System.setProperty("jenkins.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';")
```

Anyone know how change the above to work from either a local file or a remote file?

Comment: The `“script-src http://dskvm4981-iis:8080 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'”` part of the error message indicates you have a CSP policy specified somewhere other than with the `System.setProperty` properties — maybe you have it in a `meta` element in the document itself? — and that policy is only allowing scripts from `http://dskvm4981-iis:8080`. Wherever you have the CSP policy specified, you need to change it to allow the script from `https://ajax.googleapis.com/`; e.g., `script-src http://dskvm4981-iis:8080 https://ajax.googleapis.com/ 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'”`

Comment: Is there a way of seeing what CSP policies are set?

Comment: The way to see what CSP policies are set is (1) to look at the response headers in your browser devtools and check the Content-Security-Policy response header there, and (2) to check the source of the document in devtools and look for a meta element with http-equiv=Content-Security-Policy. Those two places are the only ways a CSP policy can be set.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to avoid having the report download Angular source at all by either requesting this kind of change on the [`protractor-beautiful-reporter` issue tracker](https://github.com/Evilweed/protractor-beautiful-reporter/issues) or forking the package copying the angular source and changing [the source of the script from](https://github.com/Evilweed/protractor-beautiful-reporter/blob/master/lib/index.html#L6):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

to something like:

```
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
```

having the minified angular js file downloaded to be near the `index.html` itself.

This is no more than a workaround, of course.

Comment: I did think of downloading it - found what I thought was the file which generates the main index.html and modified it (I added in some meta tags which should have sorted it) yet when the report ran again my changes were not included.  I have asked on the relevant issue tracker already if the file I modified is the correct one (even though I can't find anything else.) Just wasn't sure if there was another way around via Jenkins.